# Google Maps Blue dot in right spot, but zooms in on wrong spot

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview

```
         LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LatLng place = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        Log.d("Location", String.valueOf(place));
        CameraUpdate locations = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                place, 14);
        googleMap.animateCamera(locations);
```

The first line of this code puts the blue dot on the map in the correct spot, but when the map animates the zoom, it zooms in at the wrong spot (not far off, maybe like 0.2-0.5 miles).

Comment: are you in your code zooming to `locations` (plural) or `location`? in the posted code you use both

Comment: locations is the cameraupdate object, which is focused on my location and with a zoom level of 14 (i added the code for how i get my location in the first 3 lines) @HendrikMarx

Comment: Is it possible your MapView is overrunning the side of the screen (thus shifting the geometric "center" of the view off to one side)?

Comment: @greeble31 No, i checked the view, and its centered in the screen without going off the screen

Comment: I suppose you have determined (by looking closely at the map) that the blue dot is, in fact, on your exact location, and the camera location is, in fact, the one that is wrong?

Comment: Yes, I did. the blue dot is exactly in the correct spot, but the camera location is a quarter mile off for some reason @greeble31

Comment: Hmm, I'm just curious, if you increase the zoom level from 14 to like, 20 or something, then the blue dot must completely leave the screen, right?

Comment: yeah the blue dot wont be in the field of view then @greeble31

Comment: I suspect that the issue is because the two locations come from different types of fixes. Google is probably choosing a GPS fix for the blue dot, and your camera location is based on a network fix, due to your loose `Criteria`. I bet if you run this code while you're navigating somewhere with the Google Maps app, the problem goes away (because the GPS will be on). You may be able to fix it by changing the `Criteria`, or by otherwise ensuring the GPS is running.

Comment: @greeble31 what do you mean by loose criteria? as in add extra parameters to it?

Comment: Right, I mean, the default `Criteria` basically means, "Give me whatever fix you've got, I don't care how bad it is"